# Python webscraping issues

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scape below website for the interest rates in each currency, but it seems that the rates are stored in Javascribt and I cant find it, using "BeautifulSoup". Any ideas?

https://www.sydbank.dk/omsydbank/priser/rente

I tried the "soup.find_all" and search the code.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go would be to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), which is a way to automate browser navigation. This way, the Javascript is executed and you can then extract data from the resulting fully loaded web page.

Another way to go is to use the browser network tab and check what requests are made in the background. Using Chrome, *Right Click > Inspect > Network tab*, and more often than not you will want to filter out the results using *Fetch/XHR*.

Doing so in your case let us find out that the site is calling the following endpoint with a GET request to fetch the data you need:

> https://data.sydbank.dk/api/sybor/v1/list

It is then quite straitforward to get what you want:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://data.sydbank.dk/api/sybor/v1/list"

response = requests.get(url)

print(response.status_code) # 200

df = pd.read_json(response.text)

df
```

Output:

```
  valuta  indlån  udlån        dato
0    CHF   0.600  1.100  2023-03-10
1    DKK   0.600  3.136  2023-03-10
2    EUR   0.600  3.151  2023-03-10
3    GBP   3.600  4.100  2023-03-10
4    JPY  -0.100  0.400  2023-03-10
5    NOK   2.500  3.000  2023-03-10
```

Comment: R_D thanks for this clarification. My issue where, that I did not understand how the Javascript interacted with the website. Really good description you made.